# ReferenceError when I call a function inside another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, function, google-maps

I wrote a very simple app in which I used google drawing library (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools) to let user draw circles on a map (first circle is source place and the next circles are destinations, user can only select one source). This code also get the lat. long and radius of circles that user draw on the map.

I have access to the api (
GET https://api.dandelion.eu/datagems/v2/SpazioDati/milano-grid/data?$limit=10&$offset=0&$app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&$app_key=YOUR_APP_KEY) and I have to call this api url in order to get cell Ids inside circles that user draw on a map.

**My problem:** I see this error in console `ReferenceError: doStaff is not defined`

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drawing tools</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" href="res/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=drawing,places"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 

  (function () {
     var circle;
     var latitude;
     var longitude;
     var radius;

   function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8
   };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE
      ]
    },
    markerOptions: {
      icon: 'images/beachflag.png'
    },
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', onCircleComplete);
 }

 function onCircleComplete(shape) {
      var map=shape.getMap();
      var circle;
       //create an array where we store the circles
       if(!map.get('circles')){
          map.set('circles',[]); 
        }
       shape.setOptions(
                      (!map.get('circles').length)
                        ?//first circle
                         {type:'source',
                          fillColor:'#ff0000'
                         }
                        ://other circles
                         {type:'destination'}
                    );
      //push the circles onto the array 
      map.get('circles').push(shape);

        circle = shape;
        var radius = circle.getRadius();
        center = circle.getCenter();
        var latitude = circle.getCenter().lat();
        var longitude = circle.getCenter().lng();

         doStaff();
         alert(radius);

    }  
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
})();

function doStuff() {
  var where_stm = 'within_circle('+latitude+','+longitude+','+radius+')';
  var app_id='7b22cb45';
  var app_key='dc836a05b4f775d8813d253ba07a4570';
     $.ajax({
         url: 'https://api.dandelion.eu/datagems/v2/SpazioDati/milano-grid/data',
         type: "GET",
        'content-Type': "application/json",
         dataType: "json",
         data: {where:where_stm, app_id:app_id, app_key:app_key},
         success: function(response) {        
                   console.log(response);
                   },
         error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log("error :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    }
        });
  }

    </script>
  </head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
     <div id="sidebar-left">
        <p> Please select your source place by using drawing tools on the map. </p>
        Then, you can select one or more destination on the map using the same drawing tools 
     <p>
       <button onClick="doStuff()">Run Code</button>
     </p>
     </div>
     <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `doStuff`, but you call `doStaff`, this last one doesn't exists, you get the error, call `doStuff` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed, but still I have the same error in console! this time the error line is line 1 !!!!! while before, the error were in line 118 (where I called doStuff)

Comment: @mOna, the problem in your question was this, if solving it leads to another question, then you should ask that in a new question, I'll delete my answer now since you updated your question

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didnt know that.. so woiuld u like me to edit my question to the first version? and ask  a new question?

Comment: is fine since it was a typo, just update your current version to clarify what is the expected behavior, 'nothing happens' leads to the question 'what should happen'

Answer (score 1):

Your doStuff method appears to be inside an anonymous function scope. you need to bring it out to the global scope to be accessible in the onClick attribute.

Comment: Thanks for help, but now I get the error: `ReferenceError: latitude is not defined`  on line 130 which is `var where_stm = 'within_circle('+latitude+','+longitude+','+radius+')';`

Comment: I also deleted the line related to anonymous function `(function () {` and `})();` , now, I dont receive that error anymore, but when I click the button "Run the code", nothing happens.. Is there som problem with my ajax call?